# Timepicker in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I have included this in the .html.slim file

```
= f.input :customized_agent_timeslot 
.container
  .row
    .col-sm-2
      .form-group
        #datetimepicker3.input-group.date
          input.form-control type="text" /
          span.input-group-addon
            span.glyphicon.glyphicon-time
    javascript:
      | $(function () {
          | $('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
              | format: 'H:i'
          | });
      | });
```

Added this in the application.css.sass

```
 //= require datetimepicker
```

Added this in the application.js.coffee

```
 #= require datetimepicker
```

in the gem file i have included

```
   gem 'rails-assets-datetimepicker'
```

i am able to see the UI but on clicking the dropdown for choosing time doesn't show.

Are there any steps that i 'm missing up??

Comment: did you try as with other formats like `'d.m.Y H:i'` ?

Comment: Also, isn't it the gem reference as `source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-datetimepicker'
end` , reference https://github.com/Envek/jquery-datetimepicker-rails

Comment: i tried the same but dropdown is not coming

Comment: what's the `error` you are getting? if any, can add that to the question itself.

Comment: im not getting any error, just the time selecting dropdown is not opening

Comment: see if you are using latest version of `datetimepicker` i.e., 2.4.1 .Also, in the above github link which had shared says you need to add `*= require datetimepicker`  in `css` file and `//= require datetimepicker` in js file; which i see you have done it other way.